# Is space made up of layers?

Tags: astrophysics, space

I want to ask that is space made of layers like for example if we consider graphite then we know that its made up of layers then is it possible that space as we conceive is also made of layers and thats why no particle in our universe can't travel faster than the speed of light as because if it would try to do that then it would actually making a crack in the layer of space.

Comment: Space isn't a thing and isn't made up of anything, layered or otherwise.

Comment: What John said. But apart from that, if the structure of space somehow limited motion you expect it to limit the momentum or kinetic energy of bodies, rather than their speed. But in relativity both momentum and kinetic energy can grow without limit, if you can keep supplying a force to accelerate the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all we know to date space is not made up of layers. However, the nature of space is not yet fully understood, and to my knowledge no one has ever proven that space does not consist of layers, therefore it seems that we cannot completely rule out this possibility with absolute certainty.

A concept which might be related to your idea of a layered space is the concept of quantum spacetime, in which the time and space variables are discretized rather than continuous, see for instance [the Wikipedia article on quantum spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_spacetime).

But whether spacetime is indeed quantized is not yet known, and is for instance investigated in active quantum field theory research.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Can you please answer my other question that i have posted.

Comment: @dipanjanmitra That question has been closed as a duplicate. Other users are not permitted to answer it. If you disagree with the duplicate, then simply edit your question to explain how your question is different.

Comment: True, spacetime *may* be quantised, but a simple layer or grid scheme doesn't work well with relativity. If I have a nonzero velocity relative to you then we divide up spacetime differently, so your grid or layers won't match mine

Comment: @PM2Ring: Absolutely agree with you that a simple layer model will not work. But depending on the viewpoint, discretized space for instance could possibly be seen as some complex layer model if one uses the term "layer" in some extended sense.

Comment: @dipanjanmitra: Glad I could help. Regarding your other question this book might be interesting to you: http://store.doverpublications.com/0486409260.html